# Is following Islam supposed to grant inner peace?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

I've been an on and off Muslim. I sometimes become very steadfast in my prayers, refrain from sins, do proper Taubah etc. 
Then I still don't feel this 'inner peace' that everyone talks about. Feeling calm and loved by Allah etc. It feels so robotic even though my intentions are to please Allah.

Then I just revert to doing what people in West do such as drinking, not saying my prayers etc.

Is it true that if you completely follow Islam you should feel at peace, blessed and loved? Is this just relative or is there actually some Quranic verse or Hadees that says such a feeling would be granted?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Allah (ﷻ) says in the Qur'an:

- > "Allah guides those who pursue His pleasure to the ways of peace" (Qur'an 5:16).
- > "Unquestionably, by the remembrance of Allah hearts are assured" (Qur'an 13:28).

A sincere heart is deeply affected by its Lord's Words and Remembrance. Every "ritual" in Islam brings us closer to Allah (ﷻ); nothing robotic about bowing before the One who created us, expressing gratitude. It's only robotic when either (1) we don't understand what we're doing and why, in which case the solution is seeking knowledge OR (2) our intentions are not sincere and we're just going through motions (remember, even munafiqeen outwardly display Islam via rituals). You say your intentions are good but sometimes our intentions are not as pure/sincere as we think. So the solution is purifying your intentions/heart. These are two solutions that will improve the situation of many people if followed.

Answer (score 0):

When you regress from Islam, the inner peace that you say is absent is the constant temptation and doubt (waswasi) sewn into your mind from Sheytan.  This is primarily due to lack of depth of Iman (faith).

Living in the west and bombarded by western media, I was in a simliar situation.  The way I resolved my situation is by picking friends and peers and people I associate with that practice taqwa.  The nearest masjid has expanded much since 9-11-2001 and it is easy Al Hamdu Lilah to perform the salats and zekats.

That is really the key.  A lone sheep is easily devoured by wolves.  You need to surround yourself with those who are serious about Islam and don't associate partners with Allah.

Our prophet migrated away from his home in Mecca, Ibrahim distanced himself from his father, Lot from his wife, for this reason.  Your relations are like the clothes you wear everyday.  If your clothes you are wearing are distancing you from Allah, it is time to change them to more appropriate.

Isa ibn Merriem goes even further saying "if your arm is causing you to sin, cut it off".  This is hyperbole to symbolize shunning away from people not sincere in their faith.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to be an 'on or off' Muslim, either you are one or not. A Muslim is under an obligation to hold to the five pillars of faith. And he may, to how own hurt, neglect one or more of the pillars, except the first, *tawhid*, the Oneness of Allah and be still counted a Muslim. But if he denies their necessity, he can no longer be counted within the *ummah*.

Real faith, when held sincerely, brings inner peace; but since man, being weak, is often assailed by doubt; and also since the secular and worldly culture of the West is hegemonic in this world, attaining true faith is no easy task for those below the rank of a *nabi* or *rasul*; and this means that the inner peace and tranquility that true faith brings is not always easy to attain even when sincerely desired.